# If $\lim_{n→∞} f_n = f$ pointwise on an interval $I$ and if each $f_n$, is twice differentiable on $I$, then $\lim_{n→∞} f_n = f$ uniformly on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

If $\lim_{n→∞} f_n = f$ pointwise on an interval $I$ and if each $f_n$ is twice differentiable on $I$, then $\lim_{n→∞} f_n = f$ uniformly on $I$? Is this true?

We can say this is true if there is a function $g$ such that $\lim_{n→∞} f_n' = g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and,
the is a point $c∈[a,b]$ for which the limit $\lim_{n→∞} f_n(c)$ exists.
How do we prove this?

Comment: Am I wrong to think that $f_n = x^n$ on $[0,1]$ is a counterexample? In particular, the limit is $\delta_{x = 1}$ and the convergence is not uniform in a neighborhood around $1$.

Comment: I am not sure if this statement is correct. So you are right I guess. @mixedmath

Comment: **Hint:** Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to write $f_n(x) = f_n(c)+\int_c^x f'_n(t)\,dt$ for each $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: @mixedmath. You are right. If the convergence were uniform, the limit would be a continuous function.